# Rails 'roadie' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-email

I have HTML Emails to be sent from my Rails application. Now I have written inline styles for every element. Now i am trying to use 'roadie' gem to automatically inline my styles which I am gonna write in a seperate stylesheet.

As I am new to use 'roadie' gem I tried writing my styles in head and I sent test Email.

Gemfile

```
gem 'roadie'
gem 'roadie-rails'
```

In Mailer-layout

```
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
.logo{
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 14%;
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<td class="RB-logo">......................</td>
</body>
```

But In GMail, it does not accept my styles I have in

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually I moved to 'roadie-rails' which made my work very simple. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'roadie'rails' was the one did the magic.

In my Gemfile

```
 gem 'roadie-rails'
```

In my mailers.rb

```
   include Roadie::Rails::Automatic
```

THis does the magic.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use roadie gem in every application and it's working:

Version: 2.4.3

**layouts/mailer.html.haml**

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title X
    %style{type: "text/css"}
      = render "shared/mailer_css"

  %body{bgcolor: "#FFFFFF"}
    // CONTENT
```

**mailers/x_mailer.rb**

```
class XMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  layout "mailer"
end
```

**shared/_mailer_css.html**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.text-left{
  text-align: left;
}
// Others
```

I'm not sure why but sometimes you need to restart your server for emails to display correctly on the localhost, if you are using the letter-opener gem.

**Another note:** 
I use only roadie without roadie-rails